# Rails instance variable nil only when count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Table `ticketlines` with columns:

```
ID, TICKET, PRODUCT, REASON, UNITS, PRICE
```

Controller Ticketlines:

```
  @q = Ticketline.joins(:product, :ticket).group(:PRODUCT).select("PRODUCT, products.CONSIGNOR, SUM(UNITS) AS TOTALUNITS").ransack(params[:q])
  @product_sales = @q.result.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

In my view I want to show `@product_sales.count`

Which generates a query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, `ticketlines`.`PRODUCT` AS ticketlines_product FROM `ticketlines` INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`ID` = `ticketlines`.`PRODUCT` INNER JOIN `tickets` ON `tickets`.`ID` = `ticketlines`.`TICKET` GROUP BY `ticketlines`.`PRODUCT`
```

which shows the number of results for @product_sales.

The problem is when I try to filter the results with ransack.

Products table has columns `ID, NAME, CATEGORY, CONSIGNOR`

If I filter Ticketlines by PRODUCT it works. If I filter by CATEGORY or CONSIGNOR it does not.

If for instance I filter by category when it hits `@product_sales.count` it generates the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ) AS count, `ticketlines`.`PRODUCT` AS ticketlines_product FROM `ticketlines` INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`ID` = `ticketlines`.`PRODUCT` INNER JOIN `tickets` ON `tickets`.`ID` = `ticketlines`.`TICKET` LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`ID` = `products`.`CATEGORY` WHERE `categories`.`ID` = '289108c2-6be3-4baf-b053-96f70dc2cc5a' GROUP BY `ticketlines`.`PRODUCT`
```

What does not make sense to me is that if I remove from view @product_sales.count there are no errors. I can use category filter and it works.

The query executed is:

```
SELECT  PRODUCT, SUM(UNITS) AS TOTALUNITS FROM `ticketlines` INNER JOIN `products` ON `products`.`ID` = `ticketlines`.`PRODUCT` INNER JOIN `tickets` ON `tickets`.`ID` = `ticketlines`.`TICKET` LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`ID` = `products`.`CATEGORY` WHERE `categories`.`ID` = '289108c2-6be3-4baf-b053-96f70dc2cc5a' GROUP BY `ticketlines`.`PRODUCT` LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

What can be the reason that makes @product_sales nil only when count is used?